# getting extra + while serializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am serializing form data with jquery serialize

```
var address = $('#formdata').serialize();
```

and then I do

```
decodeURIComponent(address);
```

so my address looks like this

1762+north+street

it decodes it but instead of spaces it adds + . What can I do (instead of of course replace + with space, bad solution) to decode it properly

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `unescape`?

Comment: First you need to encode the value using `encodeURIComponent` which converts white spaces to `+` and then to get the original values back you need to use `decodeURIComponent` which will again convert `+` to white spaces

Comment: well serialize automatically adds + ... and decodeURI is not converting back to spaces